# How to convert a date character column (with Chinese characters) to a datetime format column in a table in R?

Tags: r, datetime, parsing, character

Is there a way to convert a date character column (with Chinese characters) to a datetime format column in a table in R? The column is now in the form of "xxx年xxx月xxx日". I am a bit new to R and I know that "as.date" could only read certain formats of date characters like xxx-xxx-xxx (xxx are numerical values), but failed to recognize the format in my case.

Basically the data looks like this:

```
dput(head(lands_full$contract_signed_date))

c("2004年10月11日", "2008年09月10日", "2011年10月25日", 
"2011年12月31日", "2018年08月07日", "2016年06月24日"
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: could you paste `dput(head(lands_full$contract_signed_date))`

Comment: Sure, the output is
c("2004年10月11日", "2008年09月10日", "2011年10月25日", 
"2011年12月31日", "2018年08月07日", "2016年06月24日")

Comment: paste that in your question

Comment: try `strptime(gsub("\\D","-",x),"%g")`?

Comment: Yeah I just edited, sorry for the long output before

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit confused, does the "x" represent my column "lands_full$contract_signed_date" here?

Comment: yes. it does. try it out

Comment: Thank you! The format seems to be correct, but I got all the entries in the column to be "2021-04-21 CDT", which is exactly today's date + timezone.

Comment: change the format to be `%Y-%m-%d` instead of `%g` or simply use `%F`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the package `lubridate`:

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(x, '%Y年%m月%d日')
# [1] "2004-10-11 UTC" "2008-09-10 UTC" "2011-10-25 UTC" "2011-12-31 UTC" "2018-08-07 UTC"
# [6] "2016-06-24 UTC"
```

Timezone can be set with `tz` argument to `parse_date_time`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 strptime(gsub("\\D","-",x),"%F")
```